# Image Processing program with Batch and interactive manual editing mode combined

Tags: linux, image-processing, image-editor, batch

The overall task is to generate images for charaktertokens in Virtual Tabletop Software (Roll20 in my case).
I have existing Artwork (mostly Fullbody) for Characters, Monster etc that needs to be processed.

So there is a big list of *source* images.
For each of these i want:

- enhance contrast
- change the style to look a bit more cartoonic (Posterize and add a Outline)
- mark a square selection to define which part should be used in the token
- The result of operations above should then combined with two predefined images:

  - background layer below
  - some kind of frame a layer above.

Are there any ready to use Software that can do this with minimal manual operation?

Are there *normal* Image Editing programs that can be scripted? I tested [BIMP](https://alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/) which looks good but cannot do the individual selection.

I’m aware that there exists several Batch Image Editor programs, but it seems that none of them can do an individual manual crop/cutout per individual image.

Comment: So you want an app that's half-automatic for a bunch of actions and half-manual for only one? Why not simply run automation for contrast/cartoonic look, then manually crop the results in any app and lastly run another automation for combining with other predefined images? I don't think it's much slower than the app just opening the pictures automatically for you to let you crop them.

Comment: Yes that's the solution i will choose, if nothing more comfortable exist.
I am aware that my task is very specific, but opening the processed files from Step 1/2 sorting the layers crop, export and then do this several hundred times, doesn't sound attractive for me.